# Overriding @Display

Tags: c#, view, orchardcms, models

I've different model types that are subclasses of abstract model. I'm rendering it in that way:

```
<ul>
    @foreach(dynamic model in @Model.ModelList)
    {
        <li>
            @Display(model)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

How can I define "Display" for each type (I want to have different cshtmls for each model type)? I think it is connected with shapes. How can I define one shape and view for each type? Is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution (it was not easy, because I'm totaly newbie if it is going about Orchard)
Creating new shape:

```
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("MyModel").OnDisplaying(
            displaying =>
                {
                    var elementObject = displaying.Shape;
                    var elementId = elementObject.Id;
                    elementObject.Metadata.Alternates.Add("MyModel__" + EncodeAlternateElement(elementId));
                });
    }

    private string EncodeAlternateElement(string alternateElement)
    {
        return alternateElement.Replace("-", "__").Replace(".", "_");
    }
```

Using it in a view:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var model in @Model)
{
    <li>

        @Display(@New.MyModel(Id: model.Id, modelInstance: model))

    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Seriously? Anyway, I use class name (got by reflection). On the other hadn.. maybe it could also work?